# Problems in running the dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, discrete-mathematics

I have been implementing the dijkstra algorithm for a particular problem to solve.

My problem is when I decrease the values `v--; u--;` the program automatically culminates. I do not know if there is any overflow or something in particular.

When I delete the lines where the values `v--; or--;` the program works well but does not throw me the correct answers, because I need to decrease both values.

If you can help me find the problem, I'll be grateful

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


#define endl '\n'
#define forn(i , a , b) for(int i=(a);i<(b);i++)


int const N = 1001;
int const M = numeric_limits<int>::max();
bool visited[N];
vector<int> cost(N);
vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> g;
priority_queue<pair<int, int>> q;


void dijkstra(int src) {
  cost[src] = 0;
  q.push(make_pair(0, src));
  while(!q.empty()){
    int v = q.top().second;
    int c = -q.top().first;
    q.pop();
    if(visited[v]) continue;
      visited[v] = true;
      forn(i , 0 , (int)g[v].size()){
        if(g[v][i].second + c < cost[g[v][i].first]) {
          cost[g[v][i].first] = g[v][i].second + c;
          q.push(make_pair(-(g[v][i].second + c), g[v][i].first));
         }
      }
   }
}


int main(){
  ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(nullptr);
  cout.precision(10);
  cout << fixed;  

#ifdef LOCAL_DEFINE
  freopen("input.txt" , "rt" , stdin);
#endif

   int n; cin >> n;
   int m; cin >> m;
   g.resize(n);
   while(!q.empty()) q.pop(); 
   forn(i , 0 , n) cost[i] = M;
   memset(visited , false , sizeof visited);
   while(m--){
     string s; cin >> s;
     int v; cin >> v;
     int u; cin >> u;
     int w; cin >> w;
     v--; u--;
     g[v].push_back(make_pair(u , w));
   }
   int t; cin >> t;
   while(t--){
     int v; cin >> v;
     int u; cin >> u;
     v--; u--;
     dijkstra(v);
     if(cost[u] == M) cout << "Unreachable" << endl;
     else cout << cost[u] << endl;
   }

#ifdef LOCAL_DEFINE
  cerr << "Time elapsed: " << 1.0 * clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s.\n";
#endif  
  return 0;
}
```

**Test Case**

`5 3
a 0 4 8
b 0 4 8
c 2 3 1
4
0 1
0 4
2 4
1 4`

**This is my result, when I delete the lines where v--; u--;**

`Unreacheble
8
8
8`

**Expected output**

`Unreachable
8
13
Unreachable`

Comment: Did you debug it?

Comment: Not really, but the program runs fine when I delete the values v-- and u--; but I can not eliminate them because it is necessary.

Comment: You are expected to have done your debugging before asking us for free help on your problem. Come back with your results from that process

Comment: I just added my output when I delete v-- and u-- from the code.

Comment: It seems that cost [u] is not being updated! every time you pass a new value of u

Comment: No, you need to _debug it_. Have you used a debugger before?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I notice you were also told this yesterday on your closed other question but did not heed this advice

Comment: For now I only use std :: cout, I know that visual studio has a way of doing tests but I have no experience in that.

Comment: @ChrisMichael  -- Visual Studio has a "Debug" menu option on the main menu of the IDE.  You were never curious as to what that menu option does?  VS has one of the best (and easiest) debuggers to use -- there is really no excuse, especially since it shows up on the main menu, not to use it.  Replace this line `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` with the proper headers, and then you can use Visual Studio to debug your code.

Comment: Sorry, I only use farmanager to do cpp exercises.

Comment: Visual Studio is free of charge (community edition).  Maybe in the past it was hard for students and hobbyists to invest money in the VS compiler, but now that is no longer the case.

Comment: Perfect, I'll be downloading and testing

Comment: When I hit the test I got Segmentation fault (core dumped)
when it reaches g [v] .push_back(make_pair (u, w));

Comment: Basic debugging: look at the values of variables. What are the values of `v`, `u`, and `w` when the seg fault happens?

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at what is happening in the `while(m--) {...}` loop. When you are reading the line `a 0 4 8` from input, `v` is set to zero. Then, in the while loop you decrease the value of `v` by doing `v--` setting `v` to negative one. After this you try to access `g[v] = g[-1]` in this line: `g[v].push_back(make_pair(u , w));` which causes a runtime error, because you cannot access elements of vector using negative index.